# Consultas esquema HR oracle

Tags: oracle-11g

Alguien podria echarme una mano a resolver esta consulta. Gracias de antemano.

Nombre de jefe y número de empleados a su cargo.Lo intente hacer asi:

select e2.first_name , e.first_name from EMPLOYEES e, EMPLOYEES e2 where e.Manager_id = e2.EMPLOYEE_ID;

Pero no es el resultado correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que la tabla con alias e corresponde a la de empleados y la tabla con alias e2 corresponde a la de administradores, podrías realizar la consulta con un conteo de clientes de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT m.first_name        manager
,      COUNT(e.first_name) employees
FROM   employees e
,      employees m
WHERE  e.manager_id = m.employee_id
GROUP BY m.first_name;
```

Te recomiendo organizar tu código de forma de que sea sencillo leerlo y usar mayúsculas solo para las palabras reservadas de Oracle.